# Object of class stdClass can not be converted into string

Tags: php, joomla

I am facing this issue in Joomla 3.10 with SP Page builder 3.8 PHP version 7.4.

[image: joomla error in sp page builder front end editor]

This is the code that is giving an error:
[image]

Comment: Weird, the error only comes when opening frontend editor in homepage, all the other pages are fine.

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  Please avoid using screenshots to express textual question details. Users who have visual impairments may find it hard or impossible to read a vital portion of your question.